# shift/reduce conflict in cup parser (grammar with arrarys and matrices)

Tags: parsing, shift-reduce-conflict, cup

I am writing a cup parser for a small language that is supposed to support classes with arrays and matrices as its fields. For example, if there is a class instance:

```
C c;
```

the fields are to be accessed with:

```
c.x;
c.y[];
c.z[][];
```

I am having trouble writing a production for this last part, because of the shift/reduce conflict I keep getting. This is my production:

```
Designator ::= IDENT
               |
               Designator DOT IDENT
               |
               Designator LSQUARE Expr RSQUARE
               |
               Designator LSQUARE Expr RSQUARE LSQUARE Expr RSQUARE
               ;
```

Warning : *** Shift/Reduce conflict found in state #189
  between Designator ::= Designator LSQUARE Expr RSQUARE (*) 
  and     Designator ::= Designator LSQUARE Expr RSQUARE (*) LSQUARE Expr RSQUARE 
  under symbol LSQUARE
  Resolved in favor of shifting.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The last `Designator` line of your grammer is invalid.
`Designator LSQUARE Expr RSQUARE` (two lines above) already recursively defines jagged array expressions of arbitrary many dimensions.

According to your grammar, the following would expression would be valid:

```
c.y[a].b
```

And the following would be invalid:

```
c.y[a].z[b]
```

Is that by intention?

It might be inspiring to look at the [C# grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which knows about jagged arrays.